# Spring Session integration into Spring Security - how to populate Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session, spring-security-rest

When integrating spring session with spring security I'm not sure how the `SecurityContextImpl#Authentication` is supposed to be populated when a session is identified by spring session.

**Context:**
The `spring-boot` application does not actually handle login,logout or creating the session itself. The session is created in an external, non-spring microservice and shared via MongoDB. Sharing and mapping the session information works and was utilized without issues before spring security.

**What works:**

- Spring session properly resolves the session-id
- Spring session retrieves the session (using the session-id) from the session-repository(mongo) and the attributes are populated
- The request has a populated session object including all the attributes

**What does not work:**

- Using `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("admin/**").authenticated()` and then requestion and endpoint (with an session cookie) does by no means populate `SecurityContext#Authenticated`

**Possible options**

a) I understand, I could implement a custom `CustomUserNameFromSessionFilter` to prepopulate the
`Authenticated` in SecureContext (yet authenticated=false) and place it early in [SecurityFilter chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters). In addition I implement a custom [AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-authenticationprovider) `CustomFromSessionAuthenticationProvider`, which then picks up `Authenticated` and basically sets `authenticated=true` if the session is valid (which is always true at this point)

b) Use `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` but I'm not sure how this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#spring-security-rememberme) suits that purpose

c) Somehow utilize `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` but it rather seems to be used for external auth-requests

Every option seems not right, and the need for such an implementation seems too common that there is not an existing/better solution. What is the correct approach?

Code snippets

```java
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    
    http.csrf().disable();

    // Logout is yet handled by PHP Only, we yet cannot delete/write sessions here
    http.logout().disable();
    http.formLogin().disable();
    
 
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated();
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your spring security configuration? Is your application using a `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`?

Comment: What do you define as the security configuration `void configure(HttpSecurity http)`? If yes, I added it. `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#loadContext` is called (context is `null` and it creates a new one). Do I understand this right, that this saves the prior authenticated context `SecurityContext` into `HttpSession` so it can later be retrieved when loading the same session (using the session id). So the next call loads the `SecurityContext` with the prepopulaed `Authenticated` object. This would never work for me since login (authentication) is happening on a different microservice.

Comment: Digging through the code, i understand that this is where the magic happens. When a prior request has been authenticated, the `HttpSession` stored (yet empty) `SecurityContext` is filled with the `Authenticated` object and all the information. Then this is saved in the session storage with the attribute key `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`. The next request, if the session cookie is found, it is used to load the HttpSession and thus the old attribute, which then gets restored by `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` into the current `SecurityContext` .. thus will make the user authenticated ...

Comment: .. when the AuthenticationManager is triggered. This all said, this will never work for me. The entire session is created externally, so that SecurityContext attribute is not serialized into the session (and it cannot be done from the external system) - so it will never work out of the box. IMHO I need a custom filter, restoring the `SecurityContext` into the session attribute `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`  using the data I have from the session already (username, id and things). Then this later gets picked up and treated as SecurityContext by `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` automatically

Comment: Or i could just override `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` and add a custom logic there to restore the context from the session directly (which sounds better to me)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Steve Riesenberg for providing just enough of the hint for me to find the right solution!

To understand my solution and understand when one needs to go this extra route, if first explain the default integration:

### Classic spring-session integration in spring-security

When you use spring-security including the authentication via your spring-boot app, the integration of spring-session and spring-security will become natural without anything else required.

When you authorize (login) your user initially the first time via an Authentication via spring-security, it will:

- Store the `Authentication` object in the `SecurityContext` of that request. - Then `SecurityContext` will then be stored in the `HttpSession` (if one exists), with spring-session where ever you configured spring-session to (redis/mongo).
- The `SecurityContext` is stored using a session attribute of the key `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` right in the common session data (serialized).

When you then take the session-id given to you after this authentication and make an additional request, the following happens

- spring session loads the `HttpSession` from your storage (including the `SecurityContext` in the session attribute with the key `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`
- spring security will call `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` very early in the `SecurityFilter` chain and check `HttpSession` for the existence of the session attribute `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` and if a `SecurityContext` is found. If yes, it uses this `SecurityContext` and loads it as the `current` request `SecurityContext`. Since this context includes the already authenticated `Authentication` object from the prior authentication, the `AuthenticationManager/Provider` will skip authentication since it is all done and your request is treated as authenticated.

This is the vanilla way and it has one requirement - the authentication process (login) needs to write the `SecurityContext` into the `HttpSession` object during the login process.

---

### My case - external login process

In my case, an external, a non spring-boot microservice is handling the entire login process. Still, it stores the session in the (external) session storage, which in my case is MongoDB.

Spring-session is properly configured and can read this session using the session cookie/session id and load the session created externally.

The big 'but' is, this external login will not store any `SecurityContext` in the session data, since it cannot do that.
At this point - if you have an external login service creating the session, and it is a spring-boot service, be sure you write the `SecurityContext` properly. So all other microservices then can load this session properly (authenticated) just using the session id and the default spring-session/security integration.

Since this is not an option for me, and if it is none for you, the following solution seems to be the 'by design' way in spring-boot/security IMHO:

You implement your own `CustomHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` and register that in the security configuration via

```java
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityContext()
    .securityContextRepository(new FromExternalSessionSecurityContextRepository());
  }
}
```

This ensure we replace the stock `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` with our own implementation.

Now our custom implementation

```java
public class CustomExternalSessionSecurityContextRepository implements SecurityContextRepository
{
  @Override
  public SecurityContext loadContext(final HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder)
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = requestResponseHolder.getRequest();
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);

    // No session yet, thus we cannot load an authentication-context from the session. Create a new, blanc
    // Authentication context and let others AuthenticationProviders deal with it.
    if (httpSession == null) {
      return generateNewSecurityContext();
    }

    Optional<Long> userId = Optional.ofNullable(httpSession.getAttribute(Attribute.SUBJECT_ID.attributeName))

    SecurityContext sc = generateNewSecurityContext();

    if (userId.isEmpty()) {
      // Return a emtpy context if the session has neither no subjectId
      return sc;
    }

    // This is an session of an authenticated user. Create the security context with the principal we know from
    // the session and mark the user authenticated
    // OurAuthentication uses userId.get() as principal and implements Authentication
    var authentication = new OurAuthentication(userId.get());
    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
    sc.setAuthentication(authentication);
    httpSession.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);

    return sc;
  }

  @Override
  public void saveContext(
    final SecurityContext context, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response
  )
  {
    // do implement storage back into HttpSession if you want spring-boot to be
    // able to write it. 
  }

  @Override
  public boolean containsContext(final HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY) != null;
  }

  private SecurityContext generateNewSecurityContext()
  {
    return SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
  }
}
```

So now changed the behavior of how spring-security loads a `SecurityContext` from the session. Instead of expecting `SecurityContext` to be present already, we check if the session is proper and the create the `SecurityContext` from the given data and store return it. This will make the entire following chain use and respect this `SecurityContext`